# Order by within an order by in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Im a bit stuck on an order by column. Ive got some good answers to another [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659454/using-a-parameter-from-another-query-in-a-like-clause) from stack overflow but now just need to order it correctly.

Consider I have these results (unordered)

```
|LloydA|20|
|LloydB|0 |
|LloydC|5 |
|JonesA|10|
|JonesB|0 |
|ZuberA|0 |
|ZuberB|10|
```

then want to order them first by column two but also withing it column 1 so the results are

```
|LloydA|20|
|LloydC|5 |
|LloydB|0 |
|JonesA|10|
|JonesB|0 |
|ZuberB|10|
|ZuberA|0 |
```

Because the 20 is hte maximum I want to show this row at the top and then show all the ones with the same start of name after it (ie all the Lloyd..)

I'm thinking a subselect with the order by but Im struggling. Has anyone got any tips.

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ebe6/12/0

Comment: thanks @lad2025 but this isnt quite it. What Im after is ordering on the second column first and then within the first column. Let me update teh question so it doesnt say Jones0 etc which might be confusing

Comment: `JonesA` isn't less confusing than `Jones0`... What are the formal criteria to separate the interesting part (`Jones`, the prefix) from the non-interesting part (`A` or `0`, the suffix?)

Comment: Is there always a single character at the end of the name? Otherwise how do you define the name?

Comment: The name prefix is always the same. eg Jones or JonesA. I changed from Jones0 to JonesA so that the number isnt confused with the second column. I want to sort by second column first. Ie get LloydA at the top because it has 20 wich is hte max value of column2. Then show all the ones starting with Lloyd... under that (even if hte second column is 0). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659454/using-a-parameter-from-another-query-in-a-like-clause) you don't need to extract the name, you simply have to add a GROUP MAX:

```
-- copied from the accepted answer
select p.* from people p  
join (select p1.first_name, p1.last_name 
      from people p1 where p1.id = 17
     )un
  on un.first_name = p.first_name 
where p.last_name like un.last_name || '%'
-- ADDED
order by  -- find the MAX for each name
   max(col2) over (partition by un.last_name),
   last_name
```

Comment: Thanks the partition was the key here and I was able to adapt your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that produces the results that you need:

```
WITH 
  -- "t" contains the raw data
  t(name, score) AS (
    SELECT 'Lloyd0', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lloyd1', 0  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lloyd2', 5  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jones0', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jones1', 0  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Zuber0', 0  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Zuber1', 10 FROM DUAL
  ),

  -- "u" generates the "name prefix" by removing the numbers form the names
  u(name, score, name_prefix) AS (
    SELECT name, score, regexp_replace(name, '\d+', '')
    FROM t
  ),

  -- "v" generates the max score per name_prefix ("group_rank") for each "group"
  v(name, score, group_rank, name_prefix) AS (
    SELECT name, score, MAX(score) OVER (PARTITION BY name_prefix), name_prefix
    FROM u
  )
SELECT name, score
FROM v
ORDER BY 

  -- Order by the group's rank first
  group_rank DESC, 

  -- Order equally ranked groups by name
  name_prefix ASC, 

  -- Order entries within each group by score
  score DESC
```

Of course, you don't need to use common table expressions for this. This could be done with derived tables, or views as well, or by repeating certain expressions.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/4015)

Note: Your original question referred to `Lloyd0` instead of `LloydA`. It isn't quite clear what the "interesting" part of a name really is (e.g. `Lloyd`), and what the "non-interesting" part is (e.g. `A` or `0`). But I suspect that doesn't really matter for the answer.